# Fluid-like characteristics with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, physics, game-physics

So I'm trying to write a little simulator thing with pygame, but im stuck

I'm trying to make particles that fall and settle but i want them to stack and stop when they hit a wall

This may sound confusing so here is an example:

http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-sugar-sugar/

I want to make particles that resemble the sugar in the game above:

I started by trying:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.block_list):
    self.rect.x += 0
    self.rect.y += 0
```

but then the particles just stop and they don't roll down sloped surfaces

also I need to know how to check if a sprite collides with any other sprite in its group

So if anyone knows how I can duplicate this liquid like particle movement in pygame that would be awesome!

Thank You!

Comment: I tried to write the exact game with pygame too. Let me look for the code but I left it uncompleted. Cool game btw :)

Comment: You could use pyBox2d for the physics simulation, and pygame for rendering. Here's a falling sand example: http://vimeo.com/17590907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated above, I tried to write the exactly same game with pygame too but left it uncompleted.
First of all, I preferred NOT to store these particles as different objects. Instead I used a dictionary to store their coordinates. I made it so because there are HUNDREDS of them and you have to check for collisions ~50 times per second for each of them. If you try to make them all different objects, it may go out of hand at some point.
After you detect a collision, in order to make them roll down sloped surface, let them move diagonally too. First check for the cell below, if that cell is not empty, check for the cells at bottom left and bottom right of the particle.
Btw, I found my function that moves the particles but it is not really *readable*.

```
def spawnSugar(spawnPoint) :
    global sugarList,mapDict
    mapDict[spawnPoint] = 1
    sugarList.append(spawnPoint)

def moveAll() :
    global mapDict,sugarList
    sugarListTmp = sugarList
    sugarList = []
    for sugarX,sugarY in sugarListTmp :
            # m stands for the vertical movement (1 for down, 0 for staying still)
            # k stands for horizontal movement (-1 for left, +1 for right)
            m = 1
            if mapDict[( sugarX , (sugarY+1)%mapSizeY )]==0:
            # checks whether the coordinate below this particle is empty
                k = randint( -(mapDict[((sugarX-1)%mapSizeX , (sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0) , mapDict[((sugarX+1)%mapSizeX , (sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0 )
                # If it is empty; randomly chooses 1 of the 3 coordinates below the particle (1 of them is just below and the other 2 are diagonally below)
            elif mapDict[((sugarX-1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0 and mapDict[((sugarX-1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY)%mapSizeY)]==0 and mapDict[((sugarX+1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0 and mapDict[((sugarX+1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY)%mapSizeY)]==0:
            # If the coordinate below the particle is not empty but other 2 diagonals are empty
                k = -1 if randint(0,1) else 1 #chooses 1 of them randomly

            else : # If at most 1 of these 2 diagonal coordinates are empty
                k = (mapDict[((sugarX+1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0 and mapDict[((sugarX+1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY)%mapSizeY)]==0) or -(mapDict[((sugarX-1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+1)%mapSizeY)]==0 and mapDict[((sugarX-1)%mapSizeX,(sugarY)%mapSizeY)]==0)
                if not k: # If none of them are empty
                    m = 0
            mapDict[(sugarX,sugarY)] = 0
            mapDict[((sugarX+k)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+m)%mapSizeY)] = 1
            sugarList.append(((sugarX+k)%mapSizeX,(sugarY+m)%mapSizeY))




# Values to assign before entering the main loop
mapDict = {}
sugarList = []
for x in range(mapSizeX):
    for y in range(mapSizeY):
        mapDict[(x,y)] = 0
```

Comment: so don't use sprites? just make one object?

Comment: I created a dictionary and a list of sugar coordinates. When I needed to move them, I iterated over the list and changed their values in both dictionary and list. I will try to add a pseudo-code to my answer

Comment: I know it looks scary but It is because I didn't care for the readability when I wrote this, it was just like an experiment. Now I added comment lines, you should be able to get the point, at least.

Comment: I'm not sure how using a dict improves performance?(Unless I'm missing something). -- \ You do want a quad tree, or some kind of divide and conquer to significantly reduce the number of collision checks.

Comment: @monkey If you use a dictionary as I recommended, all you need to do is to check the 3 cells below the particle for each one. If you use the way OP wrote his code, it will do 1-1 collision checks for all particles. Since there are hundreds maybe thousands of particles, and the growth rate of checking is quadratic, it will not be performance friendly. I am not an experienced game programmer, if I am missing a point,please enlighten me